# Jquery Select2 clear selection but not the select that is being changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to clear the selection from all other selects with this class but the one changed. I followed the select2 documentation about clearing selection but I keep getting a javascript error.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.select').select2();
  var locked = false;
  $('.select').change(function(){
    console.log($('.select').not(this).length);
    if (!locked) {
      $('.select').not(this).each(function(i, e){
        locked = true;
        $(this).val(null).trigger('change');
      });
      locked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select" id="1" style="width: 90%;" multiple>
  <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
  <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select class="select" id="2" style="width: 90%;" multiple>
  <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
  <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<select class="select" id="3" style="width: 90%;" multiple>
  <option value="1">Selection 1</option>
  <option value="2">Selection 2</option>
</select>
```

The solution was to lock the function when running it and unlocking it when done.

Comment: Ok I get it now. This will spawn a endless loop every time it changes a select. It will start all over and run again cuz I have the change on all selects...

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get it now. This will spawn a endless loop every time it changes a select. It will start all over and run again cuz I have the change on all selects...

The solution to my problem is in the code at my post.